# Inputstream is null when I am trying to load an image from local storage in android

Tags: android, inputstream, onactivityresult, android-imagebutton

I m trying to load an image to an ImageButton with the following

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                Uri imageUri = my_intent.getData();


                try {
                    instream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);

                    imgLogo.setImageBitmap(image);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went bad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

but I get a null instream in my ActivityResult method why?

Comment: check imageUri in your code....

Comment: imageUri get the value of ... /storage/emulated/0/Pictures

Comment: Check, Is there any file name (image file name)in that value?

Comment: this is a path correct? why its not added and the image file name if I click on it

Comment: Give your complete code of method  onActivityResult and code where you finish next activity(child activity).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this method

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri imageUri = my_intent.getData();
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
 }
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: It says now that need to be included in try / catch which it is

Comment: You can add you try catch out of 2 lines above like previous you did. It is just my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri imageUri = my_intent.getData();
    imgLogo.setImageURI(imageUri);
}
```